# Google play console name bug

Tags: console, google-play, playback, google-play-console

I changed the name of my app from Battlefield:Run to Military:Run.But I have a problem at the moment as I can't find it using Military:Run but i can find it on Battlefield:Run search.What's more weird the name of it when I find it is Military Run.Please help me with this

Comment: well it takes time to get this keyword Name changed! so you should wait for probably couple of hours and see this problem gone ! patience is the key here

Comment: Its been 2 days